# Vlookup from a fomula cell

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to use vlookup to get a value from a cell but the cell I trying to get from has a formula and as a result the vlookup is resulting in "#N/A". Does anyone know why this happens please?

Thanks,

Comment: Hard to say without more information. It might be that the values simply don't match, or a case of number formatted as text.

Comment: so I did =vlookup(C2,A:B,2,false) now in column B I have =if(C2<>5,1,0)

Comment: If VLOOKUP returns `#N/A` it means the Value you want to look up **is not** in range where you want to lookup the value

Comment: `=vlookup(C2,A:B,2,false` What is the value of C2? Also, ¿where are you using this formula? I mean, which column

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the range you are looking in has formulas should not have any bearing on the returned result.

When VLOOKUP returns an #N/A, it means that it was unable to find the specified value within the specified range. So, in your case, what ever is in C2, was not found in column B.

If you would like to catch these cases and prevent #N/A showing, you can wrap the VLOOKUP in an IFNA:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,false),"Not Found")
```

But I would strongly recommend that you NEVER use VLOOKUP. 
INDEX/MATCH does exactly the same thing, is faster, more versatile, and less fragile (for example, VLOOKUP breaks if you insert a column within the range).

The INDEX/MATCH equivalent of your VLOOKUP would be:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)),"Not Found")
```

Comment: Agree with index match especially as it does not need the data to be in the same table or even the same sheet... plus 1...